# Making auto refreshe span in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, web

I have a span in which the number (value) is displayed and it is a variable, someone does some action and the value changes, but I will find out only after reloading the page. I need the span value to be reloaded every 5 minutes. It is possible to load the entire `<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('admin') }}">Admin panel @if($admin == 2 && $reqnum != 0)<span class="badge badge-warning">{{$reqnum}}</span>@endif</a>` link because it still checks to see if the value is 0. Everything is in laravel!!

```
<li class="nav-item <?php echo (Route::currentRouteName() == "admin" ? "active" : "") ?>">
<a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('admin') }}">Admin panel @if($admin == 2 && $reqnum != 0)<span class="badge badge-warning">{{$reqnum}}</span>@endif</a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to write some ajax like this

```
<script>
    (function () {
        setInterval(function () {
//setInterval() method execute on every interval until called clearInterval()
          your Logic ..
        }, 5000); // milliseconds
    })();
</script>
```